# How to set up bindings in Ember

Tags: ember.js

I saw in the Ember documentation I could set up a binding using similar snippet:

```
householdIncomeBinding: 'App.wife.householdIncome'
```

However I would like to set up bindings by supplying objects instead of strings (path from global scope).
I need to achieve something similar to this:

```
Ember.bind(obj1, "obj1AttributeName", obj2, "obj2AttributeName");
```

Suggestions are welcome.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bindings can be connected directly to only one object. The `from` and `to` paths are evaluated relative to the object to which they're connected. These paths can also be global.

Check out the [docs and implementation](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/v1.0.0-rc.3/packages/ember-metal/lib/binding.js#L444-459) for the `Ember.bind` helper:

```
/**
  Global helper method to create a new binding. Just pass the root object
  along with a `to` and `from` path to create and connect the binding.

  @method bind
  @for Ember
  @param {Object} obj The root object of the transform.
  @param {String} to The path to the 'to' side of the binding.
    Must be relative to obj.
  @param {String} from The path to the 'from' side of the binding.
    Must be relative to obj or a global path.
  @return {Ember.Binding} binding instance
*/
Ember.bind = function(obj, to, from) {
  return new Ember.Binding(to, from).connect(obj);
};
```

So, you've got to decide which object you want to connect the binding to directly, and how it can reference the other object. You've got a couple options:

A) Provide some relationship between the two objects, and then use `bind()` to connect relative paths:

```
obj1.set('friend', obj2);
Ember.bind(obj1, 'obj1AttributeName', 'friend.obj2AttributeName');
```

B) Provide a global path to the `from` side of the binding:

```
App.set('obj2', obj2); // make obj2 accessible from the App namespace
Ember.bind(obj1, 'obj1AttributeName', 'App.obj2.obj2AttributeName');
```

Comment: Thanks for the information.
BTW do you have any idea why the binding API looks like this?
From my perspective the current binding API could be good fit in many cases but at the same time there will be scenarios where a generic binding API will be better. I don't think I should be forced to either make a direct link between the two objects or provide a global path for at least one of the objects.

Comment: That is a good question. Bindings are typically hooked up when defining models, views, controllers and templates, and are not created ad hoc. In all the typical use cases, bindings can be connected to one object and only reference the other relative to that object (or through a global reference). I imagine that bindings were designed to meet these use cases and never extended further for lack of a need. This is also a sensitive performance area, so there might be reluctance to change such core functionality without a really good cause.

Answer (score 0):

Here an example how you could setup bindings, I've taken the example from the ember.js website (http://emberjs.com/guides/object-model/bindings/) and customized it to your question,

```
App.wife = Ember.Object.create({
 householdIncome: null
});

App.husband = Ember.Object.create({
 householdIncomeBinding: 'App.wife.householdIncome'
});

App.husband.get('householdIncome'); // null

// if you now set the householdIncome to a new Ember.Object
App.husband.set('householdIncome', Ember.Object.create({amount:90000}));

// with bindings working you should be able to do this
App.wife.get('householdIncome.amount'); // 90000
```

hope it helps